# MVVM: Bring control into view

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, scrollview

I have a `Grid` with a `ScrollViewer` around it. At the top of my `ScrollViewer` is a `Button`. On a Click on the `Button`, I want the `ScrollViewer` to scroll to a `Control` at the bottom of the `ScrollViewer`.

With the following XAML I can bring the Control into view:

```
<Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Some Button" Command="{Binding DoJumpCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=window}"/>
```

The Command in the ViewModel is:

```
if (parameter is MainWindowView)
{
    var mainWindowView = parameter as MainWindowView;
    mainWindowView.myJumpTarget.BringIntoView();
}
```

This works fine. But I'm not sure if this is clean MVVM because I pass the complete View into the ViewModel.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If all the button does is to scroll the ScrollViewer, then you probably should not bind the button to a command of the ViewModel. In MVVM, everything that is purely related to the view should stay in the view. I.e., instead of the command, you could use code-behind for the Click event to scroll the view, e.g. using `ScrollViewer.ScrollToEnd()` or `BringIntoView()`.

Comment: To add to what @fmunkert said, if you think that the logic to bringtoview might be useful in other paths of your app you can create a behavior and then where ever you need this behavior you can use the behavior.

Comment: *I'm not sure if this is clean MVVM because I pass the complete View into the ViewModel* No, it's anything, but clean. Essentially, this totally breaks the MVVM pattern and the separation of concerns that it provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I first saw your question, I thought that the general solution to handling events with MVVM is to handle them in an [Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, looking again, it occurred to me that you're *not* actually handling any events... you just want to call a method from a UI control. So really, all you need is a way to pass a message from the view model to the view. There are many ways to do this, but my favourite way is to define a custom [`delegate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx).

First, let's create the actual `delegate` in the view model:

```
public delegate void TypeOfDelegate();
```

It doesn't need any input parameters, because you don't need to pass anything from the view model to the view, except a signal... your intention to scroll the `ScrollViewer`.

Now let's add a getter and setter:

```
public TypeOfDelegate DelegateProperty { get; set; }
```

Now let's create a method in the code behind that matches the in and out parameters of the `delegate` (none in your case):

```
public void CanBeCalledAnythingButMustMatchTheDelegateSignature()
{
    if (window is MainWindowView) // Set whatever conditions you want here
    {
        window.myJumpTarget.BringIntoView();
    }
}
```

Now we can set this method as one (of many) handlers for this `delegate` in a `Loaded` event handler in the view code behind:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Assumes your DataContext is correctly set to an instance of YourViewModel
    YourViewModel viewModel = (YourViewModel)DataContext; 
    viewModel.DelegateProperty += CanBeCalledAnythingButMustMatchTheDelegateSignature;
}
```

Finally, let's call our `delegate` from the view model... this is equivalent to raising the event:

```
if (DelegateProperty != null) DelegateProperty(dataInstanceOfTypeYourDataType);
```

Note the important check for `null`. If the `DelegateProperty` is not `null`, then all of the attached handler methods will be called one by one. So that's it! If you want more or less parameters, just add or remove them from the `delegate` declaration and the handling method... simple.

So this is an MVVM way to call methods on a UI control from a view model. However, in your case it could well be argued that implementing this method would be overkill, because you could just put the `BringIntoView` code into a basic `Click` handler attached to your `Button`. I have supplied this answer more as a resource for future users searching for a way to actually call a UI method from a view model, but if you also chose to use it, then great!